# How to style XMLNS elements?

Tags: xml, html, xml-namespaces

I am trying to define my own HTML attributes not for styling purposes but mainly because they will actually get functions described in javascript. Now I know HTML5 comes with the `data-` attributes but I personally like the thought of my own HTML tag.

Browsing through the internet I found XMLNS is the way to go, however, I can not find how you can style those elements.

Can someone please shine some light on the matter?

http://jsfiddle.net/KaJT8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element is called ui:tabbar, you'll need to use a selector like:

```
ui\:tabbar {

}
```

in your CSS. You'll need to test this in older versions of IE, as I believe they'll need a bit more coercing.

Though you likely know it, this isn't really what you are 'meant' to do, and you'll find many people think you are a complete nutter for suggesting it :)

Comment: Is that so? How come? Facebook used to do it with FXML

Comment: To be completely fair, I find ui:tabbar makes much more sence then div class="tabbar"

Comment: Tested (and worked) in IE6, 7, 8, 9. Firefox 3. Chrome 18. Safari 5.1.

Comment: It won't validate, for obvious reasons. That's cool that it worked in IE6/7, thought it might break there. Did you add your own XMLNS stuff as well? Facebook did it until everyone complained, so they moved to data- attributes.